# Why k-lists generalized birthday problem when $k=2$ is classical birthday problem?

Tags: birthday-attack

David Wagner in his article [*A Generalized Birthday Problem* in CRYPTO 2002](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-45708-9_19#page-1) says that in *k*-dimensional (also *k*-lists) generalization of birthday problem (GBP), when $k=2$ "this is just the extremely well-known birthday problem." Why is that so? As I understand it, in classical birthday problem we search for collisions in one list $L$, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ is supposed to be $\in L$), but, in *k*-lists GBP we have *k* number of lists, when $k=2$ it's $L_1, L_2$, we find $x_1 \in L_1$ and $x_2 \in L_2$ such that $x_1 \oplus x_2 = 0$.

So, how does *k*-lists GBP converges to classical birthday problem when $k=2$? Or I'm missing something?

Comment: @D.W. Could you please comment on this?

Comment: You can't ping people like that out of the blue, they need to actually be present in the comment chain

Comment: I already found that it's similar to [Generalization to multiple types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Generalization_to_multiple_types).

Answer (score 4):

They are essentially the same, certainly in terms of complexity. Any collision $x=y$ with $x\in L_x$ and $y\in L_y$ is a collision in a single list $L_x \cup L_y$ of size at most twice the size of the larger list.

Any collision in a single list is compatible with about half the partitions of that list into two equal sized halves. So an algorithm that finds a collision in the union randomly has found a collision in the two-list problem with probability $1/2.$

Moreover in the crypto context the lists contain (pseudo)random outputs of hashes or other crypto primitives.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't converge, it looks like it's just a different problem altogether that's been named the same (probably due to the similarities between them).

For example, [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2315408) paper, and also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Generalizations) have the definitions you'ld expect the generalized birthday problem to have.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm interested in Wagner's algorithm, in the context of Equihash. Equihash also uses **single** list, but references Wagner's algo which **k**-list. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯